# Run script that stored in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have script stored in a table. And I want to make it schedule auto run every day in SQL Server Agent Jobs by run the stored procedure. Is it possible or any idea on how to? Tried to Google search but didn't know the right keyword

This is the example of table that stored the script:

[image]

And below is the stored procedure that will be executed in SQL Server Agent Jobs

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DailyRunUpdate
AS
    SELECT Script_Value 
    FROM [Script Code] 
    WHERE [Dimension Value Code] = 'EA'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, easiest solution is to select the script_value into variable @ScriptSQL and run it with EXEC @ScriptSQL or feed to sp_executesql (the proper/better way, against bad code or injection attack)

Some reads
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/

Obvious concerns

- Injection attack
- Invalid code (use TRY ... CATCH ?)
- Execution plan for dynamic query